# jupyter map lambda result <map at 0x164ecbec7b8>

Tags: python, lambda

I tried this simple code in jupyter notebook, the result doesn't show properly.

my code:

```
z = map(lambda x, y: (x+y)**2, x, y)
z
```

instead of showing numbers, it shows:

```
map at 0x164ecbec7b8
```

I tried in Pycharm too, it doesn't work either.
How do I fix it? cheers!

Comment: In Python 3 `map` returns iterator. So if you want to get list of numbers just convert it using `list`: `z=list(map(lambda x,y:(x+y)**2,x,y))`.